# Variable dynamic font-size using single css class

Tags: css, dynamic, font-size

I’m looking for a way to dynamically increase font size depending on the users screen size in css that is variable.

I know you can use vw
font-size: calc(16px + 1.2vw);
for example, but is there a way to set the initial px size within the html and call the same class for all elements to just increase by 1.2vw ?

Not sure if that makes sense. Basically I want to have different elements with different text sizes, that grow (or shrink) at the same rate of 1.2vw.

My site for reference is: [https://techespresso.ca](https://techespresso.ca/computer-repair-edmonton.html)

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thx!

P.s. I’m currently using a separate class for each element which makes the css rather large and disorganized. I want to optimize loading performance etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your problem clearly.. but if you mean: you want to make css variable, You can!
Basic syntax:

```
:root {
    --css-variable-name: css property value;
}
```

To use variables:

```
...
css-property: var(--css-variable-name);
...
```

Example:

```css
:root{
   --primary-color: #0984e3;
   --text-color: #333;
   --primary-font-size: 16px;
   --ratio-font-size: 1.6vw;
}

.primary{
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 30%;
}
.primary h3{
   color: var(--primary-color);

}
.primary p{
   color: var(--text-color);
   font-size: var(--ratio-font-size);
}
```

```html
<div class="primary">
   <h3>Head line</h3>
   <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Compatibility and information: [Visit this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var)